# Problem using registration-free COM library

Tags: .net, com

I want to use an unmanaged COM library (specifically, Skype4COM) in a managed application without registering of this library. My steps were:

```
tlbimp Skype4COM.dll /out:Skype4COMWrapper.dll /namespace:Skype4COMWrapper
mt -tlb:Skype4COM.dll -dll:Skype4COM.dll -out:Skype4COM.dll.manifest
```

Then I've referenced `Skype4COMWrapper.dll` in my application and put the `Skype4COM.dll.manifest` together with the application executable file. Everything was built successfully, but when I try to use the unregistered library I get 80040154 error ("Class not registered").

I've also looked in `Skype4COMWrapper.dll` and ensured that it contains COM manifest entries.

What have I missed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that I've solved the issue. What have I done:

```
tlbimp Skype4COM.dll /out:Skype4COMWrapper.dll /namespace:Skype4COMWrapper
mt -tlb:Skype4COM.dll -dll:Skype4COM.dll -out:Skype4COM.dll.manifest
```

Then I've referenced `Skype4COMWrapper` in my app, created a new application manifest `app.manifest` and added the following dependency right before the closing `</asmv1:assembly>` tag:

```
<dependency>
  <dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity type="win32" name="Skype4COM.dll" version="1.0.36.0"
      processorArchitecture="x86" />
  </dependentAssembly>
</dependency>
```

`Skype4COM.dll` and `Skype4COM.dll.manifest` were put together with the application executable file.

Answer (score 1):

I also struggled with that issue. Something is just broken in latest Skype4Com library and you can't make it registration-free. I managed to install it with one single msi and it is the best that I achieved. Check this forum, it helped me a lot: http://community.skype.com/t5/Public-API/bd-p/Public_API

Comment: Have you tried to use previous versions of Skype4Com? Was there this problem?

Comment: could you suggest an exact version?